# Tensorflow-GPU; Just GPU-Memory is used and no GPU-Computing power is used

Tags: python, tensorflow

Again a Tensorflow GPU problem. I did a lot of research in the related GPU problems but I couldn't find a proper solution. If I have overseen one, I am really sorry!

I have installed tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0,
with Cuda V9.0 and cuDNN v7.05 for Cuda V9.0.
I am using a GTX1080 TI and a AMD Ryzen 1700 CPU.
When "using" the GPU, I can see an massive increase in used GPU-memory (up to 10GB). But I cannot see any increase in performance or an increase in GPU-Usage (beside memory)

I get the following output. It seems, that the GPU is recognized.

```
  Doom initialized.
2018-04-21 21:54:13.647638: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-04-21 21:54:14.329891: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1344] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.683
pciBusID: 0000:24:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.09GiB
2018-04-21 21:54:14.337566: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1423] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-04-21 21:56:24.735851: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:911] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-04-21 21:56:24.743510: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:917]      0
2018-04-21 21:56:24.746905: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:930] 0:   N
2018-04-21 21:56:24.751513: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1041] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8804 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:24:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Gian-Andrea Heinrich\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow6GPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py:198: retry (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
Starting the training!
```

I would be really thankfull if you would know a solution.

Comment: Important! It works on the mnist_deep example of tensorflow really nice. Are there any special commands needed which differ from the CPU programming?

Comment: I have met the same problem. It seems the cuDNN is not installed properly. But I have not solved it now.